# sqlite3 php - not able to open db with any db browser

Tags: php, sqlite

I've created a new sqlite3 DB with some tables using PHP. I want to open this database file with a browser/editor like Sqlitebrowser or sqlite3 command line tool, but I either see no tables or get error "database disk image is malformed". The code creates a file, I can insert and select data, but only using PHP. I think the size of the file is proper.

What am I doing wrong?

My PHP code:

    `$db = new SQLite3('myDB');
    $db->exec('CREATE TABLE events (
            id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT,
            day TEXT,
            time TEXT);'
            );
    $db->close();`

SQLite3:
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1

PHP:
PHP Version 5.3.27 on Linux

I'm trying to read the file on Windows (newest http://sqlitebrowser.org/ and http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

Comment: You are going to need to tell us more than that. What OS are you using? Does your code actually create a file at all? How big is that file? Can you insert values into it via PHP?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the first line... `$db=new(...);`

Comment: Semicolon - yes, thanks, fortunately it's missing only here. I will add now details to the question.

Comment: You missed a question... how big is the file `myDB` that the PHP script creates?

Comment: 3 077 bytes, I think the size is big enough - DB created with Sqlitebrowser (the same, empty table) has 3 072 bytes. That's why I think it's proper.

Comment: Ok, that matches the size of the file created by your PHP on my computer, so we can assume the PHP is working. What happens if you run `sqlite3 myDB ".schema"`?

Comment: "Error: malformed database schema (?)"

Comment: BUT on Linux everything works fine! So this is some linux-windows issue...

Comment: Yes, I guess it is some version incompatibility somewhere :-(

Comment: Thanks for help. I will do some additional tests and post a summing-up for others.